Gparted doesn't let me extend partition?
My disk looks as follows:
/dev/sdc1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sdc2       501758 234440703 233938946 111,6G  5 Extended
/dev/sdc5       501760 234440703 233938944 111,6G 8e Linux LVM

I would like to close the gap between sdc1 and sdc2 by extending boot partition sdc1.
However, gparted doesn't allow me to drag the boundaries of said partition, like there is no space. Yes, the partition is unmounted, and I'm running from a live CD.
What is going on here?

Probably you do not entire cylinder of free space between. And the gap is less than 1MB, do you really need this space?

Hmmmm, good points. I reduced the lvm physical volume by about 276MB, but either I made a stupid mistake, or the 276MB are not really made available. Thanks for sorting me out!

Repeated the operation to extend boot partition sdc1: I shrunk the root logical volume plus file system on sdc5, which frees like 256 bytes, I shrunk the physical volume by the same amount, but the bytes freed are not available to expand partition sdc1. What step did I miss?

Is it the free space right after the sdc1?

How can I check?

Check columns 2 and 3 in partitions list and search for gaps. Also compare the numbers with baseline

Made a typo: it is a block of like 276MB I'm looking for. I shrunk the logical volume by 276MB, shrunk the physical volume by the same amount, and now I am looking for 276MB of unallocated space.

Sorted this out: something went wrong when I repartitioned the drive, so I never shrunk the partition the physical volume was sitting on.
